# sbt can't find scala.reflect.Manifest when getting Unidoc.scala settings with scala 2.10.0

Tags: scala, reflection, build, sbt, updating

I just updated my project to Scala 2.10.0 using SBT 0.12. But now, when running sbt, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/reflect/ManifestFactory$
    at X.build.Unidoc$.<init>(Unidoc.scala:8)
    at X.build.Unidoc$.<clinit>(Unidoc.scala)
    at X.build.ServicesBuild$.<init>(Build.scala:25)
    at X.build.ServicesBuild$.<clinit>(Build.scala)
```

It seems that the problem is on `SettingKey`:

```
8: val unidocDirectory = SettingKey[File]("unidoc-directory")
```

I heard that Scala 2.10 was doing reflects different than before and thought that that was the issue, yet the Akka project is doing the same exact thing and (I assume) they are doing fine.

https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/project/Unidoc.scala (my Unidoc.scala is pretty much a copy&paste of theirs).

Does anyone know what is happening? How can it not find a class in scala itself?

Thanks!

Comment: I wrote sbt-unidoc based on their implementation if you want to give it a shot.

Comment: Need a little more information to begin to help.  Can we see your Unidoc?  It may be pretty much a copy paste, but you could be running into unexpected issues based on that.

Also, could you clean out the project/target and project/project/target directories and try again?

Comment: Given a lack of details and activity since 2012, I'd vote to close this issue.